# Creating Excel File from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

here i am creating excel file with gridview data,with below code

```
Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Customers.xls"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;           
            //Change the Header Row back to white color
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
            //Applying stlye to gridview header cells
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#df5015");
            }
            GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
```

it's working fine, but if i set gridview property as **AllowPaging="true"**, the excel file contains only paging 1 data,here how can i export all data from gridview to excel.

Comment: where are you keeping this allowpaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your aspx page, set grid's **AllowPaging="true"**

In your code behind file change your code,

```
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;    
// BIND YOUR GRID HERE AGAIN

Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Customers.xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

//Change the Header Row back to white color
GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
//Applying stlye to gridview header cells
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#df5015");
}
GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're populating your `GridView` using data which is stored in a `DataSet`, `DataTable` or `List<>` ?

If so, just take that variable, and pass it to my "Export to Excel" C# library, and it'll create a real .xlsx file for you, and can pass it directly to your webpage's `Response`.

```
class Employee;
List<Employee> listOfEmployees = new List<Employee>();

...
GridView1.DataSource = listOfEmployees;
...

// The following ASP.Net code gets run when I click on my "Export to Excel" button.
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // It doesn't get much easier than this...
    CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(listOfEmployees, "Employees.xlsx", Response);
}
```

Full source code for the "Export to Excel" class can be found here:

[Export to Excel](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

The only reason why you wouldn't want to do this is if you specifically wanted your Excel to contain the values shown in your `GridView` after they've been modified via, say, a `RowDataBound` function.

My suggestion will only export the raw data which was bound to the GridView.